# How can we show a modal automatically?

Tags: 8, ajax

When users sign up (via oauth) we need to show them Terms & Conditions as a modal. We have figured out how to make a link open a dialog in D8:

```
public function build() {
  return [
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => $this->t('Sign in to the Community'),
    '#url' => Url::fromRoute('sc_oauth.start', [], ['query' => $this->getDestinationArray()]),
    '#options' => ['attributes' => static::OauthLinkAttributes()],
    '#attached' => ['library' => ['core/drupal.dialog.ajax']],
  ];
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function OauthLinkAttributes() {
  return [
    'class' => ['use-ajax'],
    'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
    'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
      'width' => 700,
    ]),
  ];
}
```

but have no idea about how to trigger a modal automatically when the page loads. Probably it involves some JavaScript or perhaps it's doable only via settings? My only idea is to put an invisible link on the page and add some JavaScript (how?) to trigger click that link on page load but this is not elegant at all.

Comment: You can try with [entity legal](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_legal) module.

Comment: A simple solution would be to add a javascript file (library) that invokes the modal via click or something. This could also be done by CommandInvoke depending on the context of the SSO (if it's in form, then form process or ajax could be used to invoke jquery commands on selectors).